# phantomjs always return page not found on a particular website

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, data-scrubbing

im trying to get sport matches resul from this website

http://www.oddsportal.com

but any address from this website that i try i end up with page not found

while it opens in my own browser

here is a sample code

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

page.open('http://oddsportal.com', function(status) {

  page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);
  });
  phantom.exit();

});
```

i dont know how they are blocking phantom js and  i've no idea where to start .....

is there anything in phantom js headers that would alert them ?

i'll appreciate any suggestion or advice on how can i solve this

here is that website output

```
                                    <a href="http://www.oddsportal.com">
                                        <img src="logo.jpg" />
 </p>

                                    <div id="main" class="home">
                                        <div id="breadcrumb">
                                            <strong>The page you requested is not available.</strong>
                                        </div>
                                    <hr class="hidden">
                                        <div id="col-content">
                                            <h1>Page not found</h1>
                                            <p>This page not exist on OddsPortal.com!</p>
                        </div>
                                        <div class="break"></div>
                                        <hr class="hidden">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="footer">
                                        <p class="l">Copyright Â© 2008-12 OddsPortal.com (v)</p>
                                        <div class="break"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What output or error do you see after running this script?

Comment: It's not a phantomjs problem, it's a redirect problem as indicated by the 301 here: `$ curl --head http://oddsportal.com
HTTP/1.1 301 http://www.oddsportal.com/` If you can make phantom follow that redirect, it will load the desired content.

Comment: @StevenSchobert basically a 404 page not found errro (i've added the output to my question)  , there is no error i get connected to that website just fine , it just send me to page not found on each address

Comment: @meatspace thanx i know its not phantom ,  they are doing something that pervents phantom  , im going to look into it right now  , could you tell me what comment did u used to get that output ?  i've tried `curl --head http://oddsportal.com ` bbut i didnt get redirect code in terminal

Comment: ^ that should yield a 301. Use `curl -L` if you want to follow the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the user agent using `page.settings.userAgent`:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

//...
```

Source: [PhantomJS Docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html)

Comment: Or so: `var page = webPage.create({settings:{userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'}});`